# assigning html entity code in javascript button not working

Tags: javascript, html-entities, createelement

I am trying to create a button in javascript and assigning HTML entity code `&#9960;` to it. This is the HTML entity code of down arrow. Instead of showing the down arrow, the entire code is displayed in the button as is.

Below is how i am trying to achieve it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var btn = document.createElement("input");
        btn.setAttribute('type','button');
        btn.setAttribute('value','&#9660;');
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the output of my code

[image]

I expect that the button should display down arrow but for some reason it is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `innerHTML` instead of setAttribute:

```
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.setAttribute('type','button');
btn.innerHTML = '&#9960;';
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dapx0nsy/

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing `&#9960;` with `\u26E8`, try `\u2193` for down arrow. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjgfL4um/), [ref](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9B%A8)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var btn = document.createElement("input");
        btn.setAttribute('type','button');
        btn.setAttribute('value','\u26E8');
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        btn = document.createElement("input");
        btn.setAttribute('type','button');
        btn.setAttribute('value','\u2193');
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <button>&#9960;</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var btn = document.createElement("input");
        btn.setAttribute('type','button');
        btn.setAttribute('value','\u26E8');
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

First button from DOM, Second one from Script.