# How write the text «Text1 &#xa; Text2 » as an attribute of one HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax

I'm trying to write the text "Text1 &#xa; Text2" to an attribute of span element. I tried simply the syntax see bellow :

```
document.getElementById('loaderText').setAttribute('message',"Text1. &#xa; Text2"));
```

I need to keep this syntax "&#xa", because i'm using the css code see bellow:

```
#loaderText::after {
content: attr(message);
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
font-size: 5vw;
width: 100vw;
overflow: hidden;
left: 0;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: pre;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 3vw;
```

}

"&#xa" is used to get a carriage return.

The issue is, js replace "&" by "&amp;" and the carriage return doesn't work is this case.

Somebody is able to explain me if there is another way (always in pur js) ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try `\n` instead? `setAttribute` doesn’t parse text as HTML. See [Does setAttribute automatically escape HTML characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50140983/4642212).

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+setAttribute+html+entity+not+working) of [assigning html entity code in javascript button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56526299/4642212).

Comment: You are right user4642212, need to use «&#xa» in CSS, but I didn't think to use «\n» in JS. Thanks a lot ;)